# Two errors in grading program

Tags: c++, arrays

These are my two errors:

- error C2664: 'StudentMax' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int' to 'int []'
- Conversion from integral type to pointer type requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

This is my code, what do I need to fix?

```
// This program reads in data from a txt file, puts them in an array and calculates grades using that data.
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

    float lab1, lab2, lab3, lab4, lab5, lab6, lab7, lab8, lab9, lab10;
    float hw1, hw2, hw3, hw4, hw5, hw6, hw7, hw8;
    float midterm = 3*(midterm);
    float finall = 4*(finall);
    float labScore;
    float labAvg;
    float hwScore;
    float hwAvg;
    float finalGrade;
    string letterGrade;
    string studentNameFirst;
    ifstream inFile;

// prototypes for arrays
const char* names[10] = // kids names
{
    "Mike",
    "Carol",
    "Greg",
    "Marcia",
    "Peter",
    "Jan",
    "Bobby",
    "Cindy",
    "Alice",
    "Sam"
};
int* averages[10]; // number grades
string KidsLetterGrades[10]; // letter grades
int scores[4] = //elements comprising the final grade
{
    labAvg,
    hwAvg,
    midterm,
    finall
};

// function prototypes

int lowestScore(int scores[]);  
int StudentMax(int scores[]);   
void ComputeCourseGrade(int* averages[], string KidsLetterGrades[]);    
void PrintInfo(const char* names[], string KidsLetterGrades[], int* averages[]);




int main(){




    inFile.open("inputGrades.txt", ios::in); // opens input file

        if (!inFile)
        {
            cout << "Cannot open input file. "; // file not open
            return 1;
        }



    while (!inFile.eof( )) // until file ends
    {
        inFile >> studentNameFirst >> lab1 >> lab2 >> lab3 >> lab4 >> lab5 >> lab6 >> lab7 >> lab8 >> lab9 >> lab10 >> hw1 >> hw2 >> hw3 >> hw4 >> hw5 >> hw6 >> hw7 >> hw8 >> midterm >> finall;


    ComputeCourseGrade(averages, KidsLetterGrades);

    PrintInfo(names, KidsLetterGrades, averages); 

    }

    return 0;
}

void ComputeCourseGrade(int* averages, int scores[], string letterGrade)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {

    labScore = .2*((lab1 + lab2 + lab3 + lab4 + lab5 + lab6 + lab7 + lab8 + lab9 + lab10)/100)*100;

    labAvg = (lab1 + lab2 + lab3 + lab4 + lab5 + lab6 + lab7 + lab8 + lab9 + lab10)/10;

    hwScore = .1*((hw1 + hw2 + hw3 + hw4 + hw5 + hw6 + hw7 + hw8)/80)*100;

    hwAvg = (hw1 + hw2 + hw3 + hw4 + hw5 + hw6 + hw7 + hw8)/8;


    finalGrade = ((labScore) + (hwScore) + (midterm) + (finall)); //attempting to make the lowest grade of the 4 things = to full credit for that grade aka dropping the lowest grade.... ideas on how?

    lowestScore(scores);

    finalGrade = finalGrade - lowestScore(scores);

    finalGrade = finalGrade/4;

    finalGrade = averages[i]; //assigns final grade in number form to array elements of average

    if ( finalGrade >= 90)
        letterGrade = "A";

        else if (finalGrade >= 85)
        letterGrade = "A-";

        else if (finalGrade >= 80)
        letterGrade = "B+";

        else if (finalGrade >= 75)
        letterGrade = "B";

        else if (finalGrade >= 70)
        letterGrade = "B-";

        else if (finalGrade >= 65)
        letterGrade = "C+";

        else if (finalGrade >= 60)
        letterGrade = "C";

        else if (finalGrade >= 55)
        letterGrade = "C-";

        else if (finalGrade >= 50)
        letterGrade = "D+";

        else if (finalGrade >= 45)
        letterGrade = "D";

        else if (finalGrade >= 40)
        letterGrade = "D-";

        else letterGrade = "F";

        letterGrade = KidsLetterGrades[i]; // assigns letter grades to array elements for kids letter grades
    }

    return;
}
int StudentMax(int averages[]) // to find student with highest class grade
{

     int max = averages[0];
    for( int m = 0; m < 10; m++)
    {
        averages[m];
          if(averages[m] > max)
          { // finds maximum number among array elements
              max = averages[m];
          }
    }
    return max;
}
void PrintInfo(const char* names[], const char* KidsLetterGrades[], int averages[])
{

    int count = 0;
    StudentMax( averages[count]);
    while (count < 10)
    {
        names[count];
        cout << names[count] << KidsLetterGrades[count] << StudentMax( averages) << endl; 
    }
    count++; // prints names then letter grades then averages
    return;
}
int lowestScore(int scores[])
{
    int lowest = scores[0];
    for( int n = 0; n < 4; n++)
    {
        scores[n];
          if(scores[n] < lowest)
          {
              lowest = scores[n];
          }; //finds lowest number among array elements
    }
    return lowest; 
}
```

Comment: You might want to fix your willingness to actually learn programming, instead of trying to pass the exam by handing in code that you asked other people to write for you. :)

Comment: @sterlingross Did my answer help you? If so, please remember to accept it. If not, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

You're passing an `int` to `StudentMax`, which expects an array (`int[]`).

You currently have `StudentMax( averages[count]);`, which is the offending line. You're not doing anything with that result, though, so just delete the line. That should fix both errors.

Comment: Should note that that call to `StudentMax()` is not actually accomplishig anything though, because he is just losing the returned value to the ether.